# how can empty slots appear in arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I'm quite new to javascript and I can't find out at which point an `undefined` object is inserted into my array:

```
function foo(arrA){
  if(!arrA || arrA[0] === 0)
       return undefined;

  let arrB = [];
  let prevEntry = 1;

  for(let i=0; i < arrA.length; i++) {
      if (2*prevEntry == arrA[i]) {
          prevEntry *= 2;
          arrB[i] = (Math.pow(arrA[i], 2)).toString();
      }
  }

  return arrB;
}

foo([2,4,6,8,9,15,16,27]);
```

As output I get an array with powers of 2, as expected, but it's interlaced with `undefined` objects and I just don't see why.

```
(7) ["4", "16", undefined × 1, "64", undefined × 2, "256"]
```

Thanks for your help in advance! :-)

Comment: *if* means you dont set a value into ArrB at each ArrA. So there are empty positions

Comment: `if (2*prevEntry == arrA[i]){` This line.

Comment: Whenever you don't know where it crashes, stick to a try-catch block with a 'break' in it or print something in the log like the variable 'i'. And as already mentioned - pushing will solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add element to array at specific index, every not defined previously index becomes initialized with undefined value.

For example when you have

```
var array = [];
array[3] = 1
```

console log will provide an output

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, 1]
```

so the solution is , as Jonas wrote, to simply push the elements to array instead of inserting them at specific index.

Comment: oh my god... i am sorry, that's such a stupid mistake! I should have seen that myself.

Comment: In node.js it looks differently: `[ <3 empty items>, 1 ]` and in Opera - `[empty × 3, 1]`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to push:

```
for(let i=0; i <arrA.length; i++){
  if (2*prevEntry == arrA[i]){
    prevEntry *= 2;
    arrB.push((Math.pow(arrA[i], 2)).toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to this line `2*prevEntry == arrA[i]`, your code was skipping some of the indexes in `arrA` and Since the indexes of both `arrA` and `arrB` were same, `arrB` had no value i.e. undefined there. Instead of inserting square in `arrB` by index, use `push()`, this will only insert squared number.

```js
function foo(arrA){
  if(!arrA || arrA[0]===0)
    return undefined;

  let arrB =[];
  let prevEntry = 1;

  for(let i=0; i <arrA.length; i++){
    if (2*prevEntry == arrA[i]){
      prevEntry *= 2;
      arrB.push(Math.pow(arrA[i], 2)).toString();
    }
  }
  return arrB;
}
console.log(foo([2,4,6,8,9,15,16,27]));
```